# How to add a constant to a numpy array, but skipping the first row in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array as follows:

```
array([[ 0.08778,  0.99666,  0.30648],
       [ 0.41688,  2.70076,  1.10135],
       [ 1.90494,  0.91685, -0.26984],
       [-0.44512,  1.73972, -1.24406],
       [-1.68572,  1.01617,  1.01221],
       [-0.1977 , -0.77177, -0.35553],
       [ 0.61588,  3.6995 ,  1.59813],
       [ 2.98863,  0.86173, -0.59616],
       [-0.78312,  2.20935, -2.22362],
       [-2.73208,  1.02071,  1.44702],
       [-0.36006, -1.82939, -0.72827]])
```

I want to add 0.05 to each value in the array, such like

```
new_array = array + 0.1
```

Except I don't want to do this for the first row [ 0.08778,  0.99666,  0.30648]. I feel like there is a simple way to do this, but I can't think of it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[ 0.08778,  0.99666,  0.30648],
       [ 0.41688,  2.70076,  1.10135],
       [ 1.90494,  0.91685, -0.26984],
       [-0.44512,  1.73972, -1.24406],
       [-1.68572,  1.01617,  1.01221],
       [-0.1977 , -0.77177, -0.35553],
       [ 0.61588,  3.6995 ,  1.59813],
       [ 2.98863,  0.86173, -0.59616],
       [-0.78312,  2.20935, -2.22362],
       [-2.73208,  1.02071,  1.44702],
       [-0.36006, -1.82939, -0.72827]])
       
a[1:] += 0.05
print(a)
```

And the output will be:

```
[[ 0.08778  0.99666  0.30648]
 [ 0.46688  2.75076  1.15135]
 [ 1.95494  0.96685 -0.21984]
 [-0.39512  1.78972 -1.19406]
 [-1.63572  1.06617  1.06221]
 [-0.1477  -0.72177 -0.30553]
 [ 0.66588  3.7495   1.64813]
 [ 3.03863  0.91173 -0.54616]
 [-0.73312  2.25935 -2.17362]
 [-2.68208  1.07071  1.49702]
 [-0.31006 -1.77939 -0.67827]]
```

Keep in mind that write `b = a[1:] + 0.05` is not equivalent, because `b` will not have the first row of `a`. If you want to save in an another variable, you have to copy the entire array first

Answer (score 2):

To do this, first of all, you need to know basic operations of numpy.

For example, you have a numpy array named `arr` that looks like the followings.

```
arr = np.array([[ 0.08778,  0.99666,  0.30648],
   [ 0.41688,  2.70076,  1.10135],
   [ 1.90494,  0.91685, -0.26984],
   [-0.44512,  1.73972, -1.24406],
   [-1.68572,  1.01617,  1.01221],
   [-0.1977 , -0.77177, -0.35553],
   [ 0.61588,  3.6995 ,  1.59813],
   [ 2.98863,  0.86173, -0.59616],
   [-0.78312,  2.20935, -2.22362],
   [-2.73208,  1.02071,  1.44702],
   [-0.36006, -1.82939, -0.72827]])
```

This is a 2-dimensional numpy array. So you can access any row and columns, even specific value of a specific position. To traverse the array, you can use `arr[starting row: ending row, starting column: ending column]`. For example, you want to access all the values except first row by `arr[1:,:]`.
So you can get your desired output by the following code snippet.

```
arr[1:,:] = arr[1:,:]+0.1 or arr[1:,:]+=0.1 or arr[1:]+=0.1
```

The output looks like

```
array([[ 0.08778,  0.99666,  0.30648],
   [ 0.51688,  2.80076,  1.20135],
   [ 2.00494,  1.01685, -0.16984],
   [-0.34512,  1.83972, -1.14406],
   [-1.58572,  1.11617,  1.11221],
   [-0.0977 , -0.67177, -0.25553],
   [ 0.71588,  3.7995 ,  1.69813],
   [ 3.08863,  0.96173, -0.49616],
   [-0.68312,  2.30935, -2.12362],
   [-2.63208,  1.12071,  1.54702],
   [-0.26006, -1.72939, -0.62827]])
```

As you don't want to manipulate column, So you can write code without mentioning column.

Happy coding!!!